# Validation error in Entity Framewok while creating foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

I have 2 tables. One is `Preference` and the other one is `Profile`. A Profile can have 0 or 1 Preference. I am trying to create a foreign key column in `Preference` with the name Profile_id but it gives me validations errors: This is the exception:

> "One or more validation errors were detected during model
> generation:\r\n\r\nPreference_Profiles_Source: : Multiplicity is not
> valid in Role 'Preference_Profiles_Source' in relationship
> 'Preference_Profiles'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not
> the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
> Dependent Role must be '*'.\r\n"

This is my code

```
public class Profile
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual string profile_pic { get; set; }
        public virtual Watchlist Watchlist { get; set; }

        public virtual Preference Preference { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is for the preference:

```
 public class Preference
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Required]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
        public virtual Type Type { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual Profile Profiles { get; set; }

        public virtual Classifications Classifications { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Profiles")]
        public virtual int Profile_id { get; set; }

    }
```

I really have no idea what is causing the issue, can somebody help me with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF thinks you want a 1-1 relationship, which requires the foreign key property to be a key property.  But I'm guessing that's not what you actually want.   Try something like this:

```
public class Profile
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string profile_pic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Preference> Preferences { get; } = new HashSet<Preference>();
}
public class Preference
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Profile")]
    public virtual int Profile_id { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make **Profile_id** nullable:

```
public virtual int? Profile_id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be the naming convention
Try changing profiles to profile (its not a list why write profiles?)

Why did you put required attribute on the navigation property?

Comment: Still gives me the error,I tried changing it.

Comment: did you remove the required attribute?

Comment: Yes, I did remove it.

Comment: Do you get error while adding a foreign key or adding migration?

Comment: I am using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` so it always creates a new table every time the program runs . I believe its because of adding the foreign key

Comment: Why are you using DropCreateDatabaseAlways ?!

Comment: So every time I want to create a new database it will create it with the new data

Comment: If that is the case remove the earlier migration to the one in which that table was not there and then add a new migration.....   on my side its working fine